# What is the difference between Failover Clustering and AlwaysOn Availability Groups in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, database

I would like to know the differences between Failover Clustering and AlwaysOn Availability Groups in SQL Server 2012

Comment: I've flagged to move your question to dba.stackexchange where your question would be more suited. In the meantime, read [this answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/53816/65699) at dba.stackexchange on the question *"Clustering vs. transactional replication vs. availability groups"*. It has a breakdown on *FailOver Clustering* and *AlwaysOn Availability Groups*. GL!

Answer (score 0):

AlwaysOn FailOver Clustering (FCI) is associated with Windows Services FailOver Clustering (WSFC).  This is a High Availability (HA) scenario where two (or more) servers share a SAN, or WAN, or NAS.  The first server is the Active Node (Node1).  The second server is the Passive Node (Node2).  A 3rd server called the Witness or Quorum server, does a heartbeat check on both servers on a set interval, usually between 1 to 3 seconds.  If either of the servers doesn't answer the heartbeat ping, the other server is declared the primary node.  If that is Node1, then no changes occur.  If that is Node2, then the Witness server automatically fails-over the control of the databases to that node.  Failover usually is withing 15 seconds.  Any uncommitted transactions are automatically rolled-back.

AlwaysOn Availability Groups is an improvement on Database Mirroring.  Database mirroring is for single databases, and also has two or more nodes.  In this scenario, each of the nodes has it's own storage.  The mirroring mechanism will either synchronously or Asynchronously ship transactions to the mirrored node.  Synchronous mode would wait for the validation signal from the mirror before committing the transaction in the primary.  Asynchronous mode would ship off the transactions and go straight to a local commit.   AlwaysOn Availability Groups improves upon that concept by grouping databases together in Availability Groups.  When one database fails-over, they all do. You must have AlwaysOn FCI configured to utilize AlwaysOn Availability Groups, as the have some common libraries.
references:

[Adding Always-on Availability Groups to Existing Failover Clusters](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3150/adding-sql-server-alwayson-availability-groups-to-existing-failover-clusters/)

[Creating an SQL Server w/ Always-on Availability Group](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2013/08/19/step-by-step-creating-a-sql-server-2012-alwayson-availability-group/)

[Always-on Availability Groups vs Always-on Failover Clusters](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/sql-server-overview/2018/01/13/alwayson-availability-groups-vs-alwayson-failover-cluster-instances/)